# i got an error when running a project in emberJs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-data/index` imported from `ember-data/initializers/ember-data`
i am not using bower because my back end is not npm but php, can anyone tell what i am missing in my dependencies,i am using the following builds:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js,
http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v2.14.0/ember.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js
http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember-data.js.map
http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v2.14.3/ember-data.prod.js
http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember-template-compiler.js
```

Comment: Please give us reason for not using ember-cli?. You can use whatever backend, for ember project, you just need to `npm install -g ember-cli` and create new project using `ember new app-name`. that's it will take care of everything. when you do `ember build -environment=production, you will get production ready minimized `dist` folder which you can use it.

Comment: You can remove `http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember-data.js.map` and check ? since I am not sure the which version of ember-data it's using. Also try lower version ember-data

Comment: thanks, followed your advice and copy from the dist` folde the filesr and the errors are gone.